# Nodejs send ajax to client in callback method

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am writing a Cmus Remote that is browser based and uses Nodejs on the backend. Part of the app involves getting the currently playing song and displaying it to the user.

Currently it successfully runs the command gets the output stored into a variable properly, but the client side request runs before the callback of the server side function thus it retruns an empty string for the song.

Here is the code to better illustrate what I mean:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cmus Remote</title>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">

</body>
</html>
```

`client.js`

```
"use strict";
window.onload = function () {
    $.get("/songInfo", function(string){
        alert(string);
    });
};
```

`server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');
var child;


var getSongCommand = "cmus-remote -Q | sed -n -e 's/^.*tag title //p'";
var getAlbumCommand = "cmus-remote -Q | sed -n -e 's/^.*tag album //p'";
var getArtistCommand = "cmus-remote -Q | sed -n -e 's/^.*tag artist //p'";

var song ="";
var album= "";
var artist = "";

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


app.get('/songInfo', function(req, res){
    updateSongInfo(getSongCommand);
    updateSongInfo(getAlbumCommand);
    updateSongInfo(getArtistCommand);

    var strings = [song, artist, album];

    res.send(strings);

});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("Server online");
});

function updateSongInfo(command){
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        callback(command, stdout);
    });
}


function callback(commandRan, output){
    console.log("Commandran = " + commandRan);
    console.log("Command output = " + output);
    if(commandRan.includes("title")){
        console.log("Updating song to " + output);
        song = output;
    }
    if(commandRan.includes("album")){
        album = output;
    }
    if(commandRan.includes("artist")){
        artist = output;
    }

    // console.log("In callback");
    // console.log(output);
    return output;
}
```

To summarize, the ajax response is working properly, the command runs properly and the values are saved to the 3 global variables I have, but I am not sure how to set up the timing that the ajax request returns once the variables have values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because exec is asynchronous, so exec will be called, the program will continue and return the still empty data to the caller and then later it will finish with the execution data now received.

To fix this you can use Promise and async/await.

```
app.get('/songInfo', async function(req, res){
    await updateSongInfo(getSongCommand);
    await updateSongInfo(getAlbumCommand);
    await updateSongInfo(getArtistCommand);

    var strings = [song, artist, album];

    res.send(strings);

});

...

function updateSongInfo(command){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){
            callback(command, stdout);
            return resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Calling resolve() inside the Promise will complete it, while calling reject() will throw an error. Also you can give those functions parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `updateSongInfo` function runs asynchronously, so you're server is sending back a response before the update has completed.  What you'll need to do is either implement Promises or a callback to run after those functions have completed. I would probably suggest that you not use global variables here, but instead return the result each time. Here's an example:

```
app.get('/songInfo', function(req, res) {
  var song, artist, album;
  updateSongInfo(getSongCommand, function(err, result) { 
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    song = result;
    updateSongInfo(getAlbumCommand, function(err, result) {
       if (err) return res.send(err);
       album = result;
       updateSongInfo(getArtistCommand, function(err, result) {
         if (err) return res.send(err);
         artist = result
         // Now your globals will be fulfilled
         return res.send([song, artist, album]);
       });
    });
  });
});

function updateSongInfo(command, cb){
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    callback(command, stdout, cb);
  });
}


function callback(commandRan, output, cbFunction){
  console.log("Commandran = " + commandRan);
  console.log("Command output = " + output);
  if(commandRan.includes("title")){
    console.log("Updating song to " + output);
    song = output;
  }
  if(commandRan.includes("album")){
    album = output;
  }
  if(commandRan.includes("artist")){
    artist = output;
  }

  // console.log("In callback");
  // console.log(output);
  return cbFunction(null, output);
}
```